# Android images not scaling properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I still can't understand how images are scaled. I have this 600px x 600px image. I scaled it to different sizes (ie. to 450 x 450, 300x300 and 225x225). I did that in order for devices with different screen densities adjust the size of the image. Then I placed an imageview to a generic 1280x800 10.1" tablet, which is mdpi as stated by the ADT. It views properly on the 10.1 tablet graphical layout but seems oversized on the other devices especially on the phone category. Here is the link to image:

[image]

The layout width and height are also set to wrap_content, should I set it to a value in dp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since, its an mdpi tablet, the resource is being picked from the drawable-mdpi folder and thus appearing that small.

Perhaps you can create a layout-mdpi-xlarge folder and then in that layout refer a copy of the image from the xhdpi folder.

Comment: Should I place the layout-mdpi-xlarge folder inside the res or inside the layout folder?

Comment: it should be placed inside res, peer to the default layout folder